# How to access ADO disconnected recordset object set in one excel workbook from another excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado, recordset

Is it possible to have a recordset object created and set in one workbook but access this recordset object and data from another workbook's vba code? I was thinking maybe getobject could be used to capture it from another workbook but I cannot find any resources on this.

*edit here is my ado code for creating ado

```
Public DatabaseMethods As New DatabaseTools
Public testRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub LoadTables()

   Call DatabaseMethods.SQLCreateDatabaseConnection
   DatabaseMethods.SQLOpenDatabaseConnection ThisWorkbook.FullName

   Set testRecordset = DatabaseMethods.SQLQueryDatabaseRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & DatabaseMethods.TableAddress(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")))

   DatabaseMethods.SQLCloseConnection
   DatabaseMethods.SQLDestroyDatabaseConnection

End Sub

Public Function SQLQueryDatabaseRecordset(SQLQuery As String) As ADODB.Recordset

   'Create RecordSet
   Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   oRs.LockType = adLockReadOnly

   Sleep 100
   DoEvents

   'Open Record Set by executing SQL
   oRs.Open SQLQuery, oConn

   'Disconnect the recordset
   Set oRs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

   'Return recordset
   Set SQLQueryDatabaseRecordset = oRs

   Set oRs = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Do you have both workbooks opened the same time? Are they opened with the different `Application` objects (i. e. launched in separate EXCEL.EXE processes)? How do you launch VBA code in the workbooks?

Comment: They are opened in the same instance but we are considering opening them in seperate instances.

Comment: I can show my code of how the recordset is set above

Comment: What is `DatabaseTools`?

Comment: Its just a class object that SQLQueryDatabaseRecordset function sits in but also there are some other subroutines in there that are called to create the connection and so forth. However, this function is the key to creating the ado disconnected recordset.

Comment: Generally there are two ways: 1) to save the contents of the recordset to a file in 1st workbook, and load the contens by the recordset in 2nd workbook, or 2) share recordset object from 1st workbook to 2nd workbook in another process.

Comment: So option 2 seems to be what i want. So how do you share the recordset object between the two workbooks?

Comment: How will you open worksbooks in separate processes?

Comment: Do you need to send the recordset to another workbook only, or to return some new records back to source workbook also?